# Navbar automatically goes Mobile mode despite being on desktop

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, navbar

I haven't been working on code for ages and I'm facing an issue that is getting me crazy cause I can't even start doing anything. I'm working on the very base of my website and when I try my page the navbar automatically goes on Mobile mode while I'm on desktop.

I tried on Chrome and Firefox with the same results : a shrinked navbar on full-size page (it's not even working correctly as it's not the good size). Reducing the window's size will make the mobile navbar work correctly but impossible to get a normal one.
I've tried different styles of navbar from Codepen to see if my code was wrong but same problem. I even tried using Bootstrap 3 instead of 4 and the code gets even worst.
This one for example is wrong : https://codepen.io/mmgolden/pen/JNewdL

HTML Head :

```
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

  <script src="assets/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

  <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

HTML Body :

```
<body>

     <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarMobile" aria-controls="navbarMobile" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="nav-left">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <a class="navbar-brand mx-auto" href="#"><div id="logo"></div></a>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <!-- Mobile -->
    <div class="collapse" id="navbarMobile">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Mobile Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Mobile Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Mobile Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Mobile Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Mobile Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Mobile Link</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
<div class="slider">
</div>
</body>
```

CSS :

```
       .slider {
         background: #333;
         height: 400px;
         width: 100%;
         }

#logo {
  background: #ccc;
  width: 150px;
  height: 70px;
}

.navbar-toggler {
  margin-top: 15px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .navbar {
      height: 130px;
   }
  #logo {
    width: 260px;
    height: 120px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: -20px;
  }
  .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    padding-right: 75px;
  }
  #nav-left {
    padding-left: 30px;
  }
}
```

Screenshot : https://ibb.co/KDFqfTH
I need it it show up normally on desktop and shrink on mobile/tablet.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: `@media screen and (min-width: 992px)` is for tablet, landscape iPad, lo-res laptops ands desktops. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370690/media-queries-how-to-target-desktop-tablet-and-mobile]

Comment: Try `@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {` instead